Is there any way I can change the color of the JButton element
This is the grid that i want to implement
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DemoPanel extends JPanel {

    // Screen settings
    final int MAX_COL = 15;
    final int MAX_ROW = 10;
    final int NODE_SIZE = 70;
    final int SCREEN_WIDTH = NODE_SIZE * MAX_COL;
    final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = NODE_SIZE * MAX_ROW;

    // Node
    Node[][] node = new Node[MAX_COL][MAX_ROW];
    Node startNode, finishNode, currentNode;

    public DemoPanel() {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(MAX_ROW, MAX_COL));

        // Place Node
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;

        while ( col < MAX_COL && row < MAX_ROW ) {

            node[col][row] = new Node(col, row);
            this.add(node[col][row]);

            col++;
            if ( col == MAX_COL ) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }

        // set start and finish node
        setStartNode(3, 6);
        setFinishNode(11, 3);
    }

    private void setStartNode(int col, int row) {
        node[col][row].setAsStart();
        startNode = node[col][row];
        currentNode = startNode;
    }

    private void setFinishNode(int col, int row) {
        node[col][row].setAsFinish();
        finishNode = node[col][row];
    }
}


Here is the node class.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Node extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    Node parent;
    int col;
    int row;
    int gCost;
    int hCost;
    int fCost;

    boolean start;
    boolean finish;
    boolean solid;
    boolean open;
    boolean checked;

    public Node(int col, int row) {

        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;

        setOpaque(true);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setFocusPainted(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void setAsStart() {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        setText("Start");
        start = true;
    }

    public void setAsFinish() {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        setText("Finish");
        finish = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Node (" + col + ", " + row + ") clicked!");
        this.repaint();
        this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    }
}


Here's how the output looks like in the above code
But what i want to do is change the color of the white part not the color behind it. Is there anyway i could do that?
I tried
//setBorderPainted(false);
This is what happened after i tried setBorderPainted(false)
Also i tried
this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
but even with this there was no way i could find to add a border color in order to seporate the nodes.
